# Observable timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, rx-java

Assume that I have following.

```
Observable.range(1,1000)
.flatMap(i -> Observable.just(i)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()
    .map(i2 -> calculate(i2))
).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

In here I have an observable from 1 to 1000 and each number is mapped using calculate()(a large mehod) in different threads.I need to set a timeout until some amount of items returned.

  Say I have a timeout of 2 seconds.

  I need 2-50 items to be subscribed.(At least 2 items should be subscribed but not more than 50 items)

  If 2 items do not emitted within 2 seconds restart timeout.

  Say 10 items returned within timeout.Then no problem execute the rest of the code.

How can I do this using Rx Java?

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved using buffer() in rx-java instead of using timeout()

Comment: example please.